# Geoserver and PostGIS in Heroku?

Tags: heroku, postgis, geoserver

i'm looking for information if i can install geoserver in Heroku, i found that heroku supports PostGIS, but don't found any information about Geoserver in heroku. Any one installed Geoserver in heroku, or where i have to install geoserver.

Thanks all. Greats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after a lot of search i figured out that is a little complicated to upload Geoserver to heroku. Then i found that some people upload Geoserver to Openshift. I found this tutorials that explain perfectly how to do that.

The first link it's from openshift user and the second link it's the same but in spanish:

https://www.openshift.com/blogs/build-your-own-google-maps-and-more-with-geoserver-on-openshift#comment-39747

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/geoserver-es/DnEhpL_DPYs

Answer (score 3):

I've written a script that makes the task a bit easier, the readme explains how it works. You can run the script or follow it's steps manually.

http://github.com/w8r/openshift-geoserver/